# Hybrid quicksort+insertion sort in C

Tags: c

im asked to do two versions of hybrid quicksort;

1. When the elements are smaller than 10 call insertion sort to sort each subproblem
2. When the elements are smaller than 10, stop quick sort and use insertion sort for the whole unsorted array i got that time.

This is my my quicksort code for the first exercise. I cant seem to find the coding difference between each. I know that's its a very small difference. I tried a lot

```
void quickSort(int array[], int start, int finish){
    int pivot;
    if ( low < high ){
        pivot = partition(A, start, finish);
        if ((high - low) < 10){
            insertionSort(A, start, finish);
        }
        quickSort(A, low, pivot - 1);
        quickSort(A, pivot + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is to insertion sort small partitions as they are found during the recursive quickSort function:

```
void quickSort(int *A, int low, int high) {
    if ((high - low) < 10) { // insertionSort small partitions
        insertionSort(A, low, high);
        return;
    }
    if (low < high) {
        int pivot = partition(A, low, high);
        quickSort(A, low, pivot - 1);
        quickSort(A, pivot + 1, high);
    }
}
```

The second option is to ignore small partitions during recursion. That leaves the array as a series of small nearly-sorted partitions. A final insertion sort then finishes sorting the array. This example moves the recursive portion into its own helper function.

```
void quickSort_helper(int *A, int low, int high) {
    if ((high - low) > 10) { // ignore small partitions
        int pivot = partition(A, low, high);
        quickSort_helper(A, low, pivot - 1);
        quickSort_helper(A, pivot + 1, high);
    }
}

void quickSort(int *A, int low, int high) {
    quickSort_helper(A, low, high);
    insertionSort(A, low, high);
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this code but it shows the general idea.